# Load my.settings from form2 when form1 starts

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, basic

I've tried now many solutions but none of the solutions worked.

To explain the situation:

I have 2 Forms. `Form1` is the "main" form and `Form2` is the "settings-form". In `Form2` I can check/uncheck if `Form1` is at the top (TopMost) or not. The `checkstate` gets saved in My `.Settings`, but it loads the `checkstate` only when I open `Form2` (settings-form). I want to load the settings when `Form1` starts.

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: First, are you trying to make the settings take effect immediately when the checkbox is un/checked, or are you talking about after the settings form has been closed. Second may be irrelevant depending on your answer to the first question, but how are you opening the settings form (i.e. like showdialog, or just show)?

Comment: So, when i close the settings form the effect is taken for form1 and when i open the settings form again, the checkstate is saved. But when i close the application and start it again the effect isn't loaded, but when i open the settings form, the checkstate is loaded and saved from before

Comment: Well without seeing the code I can only speculate, but it sounds like you aren't setting the Form1's properties in the New() sub correctly, or not at all. Somewhere in New() you should be setting `Me.TopMost = CType(Me.Settings.[urSettingName], Boolean)`. If you're not, add that. If you are, then put a breakpoint there and see what it's retrieving. Like I said, it's hard to guess without seeing the code.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I don't want to post the code. But I've tried your code and it works great. I'm very grateful to you!